# Are hospitality industry questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just started an [Area 51 proposal for people working in the hospitality industry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86541/hospitality-industry) and I was wondering if questions dealing with hotel/motel/restaurant management and so on were already on-topic here.

Pretty much just checking if these bases are already covered or if there may be some interest in covering them.

Answer (score 5):

No they are not, questions about *managing* this industry are totally off-topic. However, staying, eating in or using these facilities are something else, I do not think that proposal is intended for these topics which are totally on-topic here.

Regarding the proposal, we have some users who are really experienced in this field, posting this proposal here is a good idea after all, I am sure they will be happy to help in making that proposal see the light.

One more thing, I think WorkPlace.SE covers this, at least partially.

Comment: I would expect a lot of overlap with Workplace, but I was a little unsure about Travel.

Comment: My understanding is, it's a case of, is the question from the point of view of the traveller (the customer), and could an experienced traveller answer it? So "Do any hotels do X?" might sometimes be on topic, as might questions about how certain policies or practices impact a traveller's experience, but business-oriented questions definitely wouldn't be.

Comment: Actually I think there's plenty of industry-side questions that would be on-topic right here, but we don't get so many. The closest I can think of is a couple of people asking questions about using booking systems that they obviously use in their industry job. But there are not doubt all kinds of industry-side questions which are about business and other topics and not about travel.