# Questions from the side of service providers, guest house owners, etc

Tags: discussion

For example, [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123414/only-accept-prepaid-booking-com-booking) (now deleted, needs 10k rep to read) is a question made by a guest house owner regarding acceptance of certain types of payments.

Are these kind of questions on topic? if so what tags can we use?

Comment: Very similar (possible dupe?): [Are hospitality industry questions on-topic here?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/are-hospitality-industry-questions-on-topic-here) ...but wait, you answered that one... and your answer there ("totally off-topic") is the opposite to your comment here? ("should be on-topic..." / "I totally agree") What have I missed? :-)

Comment: I totally forgot about that, it was 3.5 years ago. I guess people change over time. I would downvote myself if I could 

Answer (score 12):

My view is that the travel-related aspects to running hospitality businesses should be on topic, but not those that are purely business related.

The linked question is specifically about configuring booking.com policies for prepaid bookings. To me, this is too much about the details of operating a business and not sufficiently about travel. We wouldn't consider a question about how to take prepayments using hotel Property Management System software on topic (because it's about using hotel software, not traveling), and the same applies on the smaller scale of guest house operators. Taking questions about running hospitality businesses leads to even more questions that get further away from travel: taxes, compliance with local rental laws, etc... There are dedicated forums for people who rent out their properties that are better venues for such business questions.

However, I'd welcome questions that involve travel and travelers from the service provider's side. These could be about cultural differences, language barriers and communications, traveler expectations, or perhaps how listings are described to travelers.

Answer (score 3):

I think questions on providing hospitality business services should be on-topic.

We don't have much precedence in receiving questions related to running a hospitality business, but I think they could be interesting and enrich the site.  There's a lot travellers can learn from hosts and vice versa.  Of course, we do have hosts active on the site, but the questions they answer (or ask) are still from the perspective of a traveller rather than a host.

Comment: I totally agree with you 